# Ubuntu 17.10 on Toshiba Chromebook no sound

Tags: 17.10

Hello i installed a copy of Ubuntu 17.10 in my Toshiba Chromebook 2. The installation is already complete without errors.  It's working.  Only one issue.  I can't hear anything! On setting window I can find only dummy output.  I tried alsamixer and I checked all levels and channels. In software and drivers I can't find any audio driver.  What can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

It's a common issue for Toshiba Chromebook laptops but a fedora user figured out a fix. Follow the instuction with the necessary adjustments:

1. Export the "asound.state" file from Chrome Os.
2. Make sure Alsa isn't running.
3. Overwrite /var/lib/alsa/asound.state with the Chrome Os file.
4. Again, as root, edit the `[Element Speaker]`section of
   `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-headphones.conf`,
   making `switch = mute` and `volume = zero`. This enable the speaker
   muting when a pair of headphones is plugged in.
5. Reboot.

Here the original post:
https://plus.google.com/+JamesFuBEEFCAKE/posts/Tf4Pc5Z8reH

and here look at post #8 maybe come handy:
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/toshiba-chromebook-2-audio-cb35-4175558711/

This is the troubleshooting for alsa:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

Comment: Thanks I did all of this steps but still no sound. Now, when I go to settings> sound> exit I can't find any device and the volume level is unselecteable!

Comment: mmm... double check the procedure maybe you missed something, in e.g. be sure to kill alsa before file overwrite... then check all the alsa troubleshoting to try to isolete the issue. Link added to my answer.